# how do you change base/root url in ember cli from default root '/' to '/home'?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have generated a route 'home' and I would like to change my base url '/' to be 'home' i have tried adding this line of code to the router.js

```
App.Router.reopen({
  rootURL: '/blog/'
});
```

I have also tried setting my base-url in config/environment.js to '/home/'

Answer (score 5):

```
// app/routes/application.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function () {
        this.transitionTo('home');
    }
});


// router.js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', { path: '/home' });
});
```

Comment: Thanks looks like you can also add this to router map

this.resource('your_new_root', { path: '/' });

Comment: For version > 1.11.0 use - this.route('yournewroot',{path:'/'})